# Rails - how many times to write 'end' in an if/elsif/else statement

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out Rails 4.

I am using CanCanCan for abilities and am getting an error in my ability.rb.

The relevant error thinks I have an extra 'end' in the below block?

```
def program_qanda
  # can ask questions on programs
      # TO DO: create this 
      can :cr, ProgramQuestions if can? :read, Programs
      end
      can :read, ProgramAnswers, if can? :read, ProgramQuestions 
      end 
      can :ud, ProgramQuestions.user_question.unanswered
      #can read answer to Q     
end
```

I can't see where that would be and I have another method defined (in the similar format, above this method and there is no error coming up which references that method.

The line reference of the error is pointing to the last end in that block.

It's making me wonder if the line reference is perhaps an error and the problem starts higher up where I define my roles. The relevant initialise statement is:

```
 def initialize(user)

      alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud

      alias_action :create, :read, :to => :cr

      alias_action :create, :read, :update, :to => :cru

      alias_action :update, :destroy, :to => :ud

    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

      new_registrant

      if user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:pending)

      maintain_profile

    elsif user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:student)

      student_abilities

    elsif  user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:educator)

      educator_abilities


    elsif user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:adviser)

      adviser_abilities


    elsif user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:participant)

      participant_abilities

    elsif user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:guest)

      guest_abilities

    elsif user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:manager)

      manager_abilities

    else user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
    end

  end
```

Do I need to have more end statements in this block?  What are the rules? Do you need one 'end' for every 'if' and one end for every 'else' and one end for every 'elsif'? I thought it would be enough to have one end for the 'if' and one end for the def at the top.

Can't find references to this - all examples just show the statement, not whether the 'ifs' fit into blocks that pick up all the extra 'end' statements.

Comment: To stop getting this error, I had to add 13 extra 'end' statements to the end of my abilty.rb class. I don't understand why they're required. I don't have 13 of anything that I can see. All my methods are closed (with what I think of as the right number of end statements. I found this by adding end statements one by one until the error went away - so no real learning, but a solution if it helps others get on with things. Very keen to find the rules though  - if anyone knows where to find them, I'd really appreciate a steer.

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide 
and
https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide

Comment: Great - thanks for these. It looks like a really helpful resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
else user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
end
```

is not valid. You probably want:

```
elsif user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
end
```

**EDIT:**

A significant amount of this code is not quite right. I think a large part of it could be solved by formatting. Other parts need to be adjusted to valid syntax. If You qualify a method call with parameters with an if, it is better to enclose the parameters with parenthesis. Also, you have an additional comma. Change your code above to look like this:

```
def program_qanda
  # can ask questions on programs
  # TO DO: create this 
  can( :cr, ProgramQuestions ) if can?( :read, Programs )
  can( :read, ProgramAnswers ) if can?( :read, ProgramQuestions ) 
  can( :ud, ProgramQuestions.user_question.unanswered )
  #can read answer to Q     
end
```

Then go through your entire class, correcting the formatting and syntax as you go along. It might be helpful to the learning process to use an IDE. I like RubyMine, personally (no affiliation, just a great product). It has an auto-format feature and highlights syntax errors, just to name a few features that may be of interest to you.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks. I thought the last one had to be else? there is nothing else after this. Are you sure you can end with elsif with no other option if the answer there is false?

Comment: It sure can. The else is just if you need a catch all, if none of the other conditions are satisfied. if you want to make it an else, you can use something like `can( :manage, :all) if user.admin?` but it ends up doing the same thing, and being harder to read.

Comment: I tried replacing else with elsif (and removing the 'end' statements from the one line if statements and still get this: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: Thanks Brad, I tried this- but I get an error looking for more end statements. I don't know where to put them.

Comment: It looks like this method is getting away from you... For example, notice how many times you repeat `user.try(:profile).present?`. How could you reduce that? Do you see a pattern with what is left? How could you simplify that? You might get a kick out of https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers. Good luck!

Comment: Well, add it in, then... It would help if you were to properly indent your code. Formatting not only makes it easier to parse logical blocks while reading, it also helps you structure your code properly.

Comment: Where should I add it? Do I need an 'end' for every 'elsif' at the end of the block? Or does it mean at the end of the class. I've tried several variations on where to try putting it but am struggling to find the rules on how many ends are need with if else blocks.

Comment: So far I have added an extra 6 'end' statements to the end of the class and it is still asking for more. The only thing long enough to have that many things to close is the role initialise statement. That's why I'm wondering whether I need to add 'end' after every 'eslif'

Comment: Yes, I know you don't need all of the parenthesis, just the two in front of the ifs, but I put them all for consistency.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll give it a try. I'm using sublime for text editing. I stopped using Ruby Mine - i found it incredibly frustrating. Thanks very much for the example. I've never seen code expressed int he way you have shown. I'd love to know where to find the rules for how to write these functions. i'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Basically, you never really need parenthesis. But sometimes, like when you have an if after it, it is hard for the interpreter to know where to "draw the line" on method parameters. This is compounded by the extra comma. While you are learning, it is probably easiest just to use them everywhere, to reduce frustration.

Answer (score 1):

```
can :cr, ProgramQuestions if can? :read, Programs
```

This is an inline condition, it translates to:

```
if can? :read, Programs
  can :cr, ProgramQuestions
end
```

Inline condition only applies to the code before it in the same line and does not require `end`. So, you do not have an extra `end` there - you have too much `end`s.

Comment: I took all of those extra ends out, but now get this; syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
Is it possible that I need some more of them in the initialise function?